# core.mjs:6468 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'open')

Tags: angular

My TS function is:

```
openSubAddModal() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open( AddEmployeeComponent,  {
      width: '50%',
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result:any) => {
      this.getList();
    });
}
```

How to fix
`core.mjs:6468 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'open')`?

Comment: is `import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';` in app.module.ts? is `import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';` in the component.ts where you use dialog? and is `dialog` declared in constructor as `private`?

Comment: yes , but I am using MatDialogRef and declared as public

Comment: I think that is a problem, currently the correct way to use dialogs is to import `import {MatDialog} from '@angular/material/dialog';`, check the example https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/examples